# sorting <li> list with its style

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have a list as bellow that is created dynamically:

```
<ul id="Bucket-1" class="list1" data-listidx="11">
<li><div style="cursor: pointer;">BYBO2</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">FURG4</div></li>
<li><div style="cursor: pointer;">HCLB8</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">KVQF1</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">LYPI6</div></li>
<li><div style="cursor: pointer;">MLET3</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">MPZM9</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">RFHP7</div></li>
<li style="display: none;"><div style="cursor: pointer; display: none;">TEAR5</div></li>
</ul>
```

I have to apply sorting throgh jquery to `<li>` on above, in which `<li>` does not contain `style="display:none"`

Comment: I didn't get you, how do you want to sort it ? Do you have any plan ?

Comment: check this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/

Comment: it means sorting should only apply on those li in which li does not contain style="display:none";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use css class instead of `display:none`, and use simple solution in [THIS POST](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)
css:

```
.visible-li{}
.hidden-li{display:none;}
```

html:

```
<ul id="Bucket-1" class="list1" data-listidx="11">
<li class="visible-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">BYBO2</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">FURG4</div></li>
<li class="visible-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">ACLB8</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">KVQF1</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">LYPI6</div></li>
<li class="visible-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">MLET3</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">MPZM9</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">RFHP7</div></li>
<li class="hidden-li"><div style="cursor: pointer;">TEAR5</div></li>
</ul>
```

and finally use solution in recommended post

see it on [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/y9UrR/)